# Spark | For a synchronous request/response use case

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib

Spark Newbie alert. I've been exploring the ideas to design a requirement which involves the following:

1. Building a base predictive model for Linear Regression(One off activity)
2. Pass the data points to get the value for the response variable.
3. Do something with the result.
4. At regular intervals update the models.

This has to be done in a sync (req/resp) mode so that the caller code invokes the prediction code, gets the result and carries on with the downstream. The caller code is outside spark (it's a webapp).

I'm struggling to understand if Spark/Spark Streaming is a good fit for doing the Linear Regression purely because of it's async nature.

From what I understand, it simply works of a Job Paradigm where you tell it a source (DB, Queue etc) and it does the computation and pushes the result to a destination (DB, Queue, File etc). I can't see a HTTP/Rest interface which could be used to get the results.

Is Spark the right choice for me? Or are there any better ideas to approach this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If i got it right then in general you have to solve three basic problems:

1. Build model
2. Use that model to perform predictions per sync http
   request (for scoring or smth like this) from the outside (in your
   case this will be webapp)
3. Update model to make it more precise
   within some interval

In general Spark is a platform for performing distributed batch computations on some datasets in a pipeline manner. So with job paradigm you were right. Job is actually a pipeline which will be executed by Spark and which have start and end  operations. You will get such benefits as distributed workload among your cluster and effective resource utilization and good (in compare with other such platforms and frameworks) performance due to data partiotioning which allows to perform parallel executions in narrow operation.

So for me the right solution will be to use Spark to build and update your model and then export it in some other solution which will serve your requests and use this model for predictions.

> Do something with the result

In step 3 you can use kafka and spark streaming to pass the corrected result and update your model's precision.

Some useful links which can probable help:

https://www.phdata.io/exploring-spark-mllib-part-4-exporting-the-model-for-use-outside-of-spark/

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13028/loading-and-querying-a-spark-machine-learning-model-outside-of-spark

http://openscoring.io/blog/2016/07/04/sparkml_realtime_prediction_rest_approach/